React 19 - use api, re-fetch from onclick event
Using the new use api from React 19, how can I re-fetch with an onClick event?
Before with useEffect is was really easy cause the fetch function was called from useEffect or from an onclick event.
import { use, Suspense } from 'react'

const fetchData = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')
  return res.json()
}

const JokeItem = () => {
  const joke = use(fetchData())
  return <h2>{joke.value}</h2>
}

export default function Joke() {
 
  return (
    <Suspense>
      <JokeItem /> 
      <button onClick={() => {}}>New Joke</button>
    </Suspense>
  ) 
}


I upvoted because I think this is a well written question, but I think you should consider not using use for this yet. The code you showed immediately runs afoul of this warning and will need some significant changes to work correctly

An 'unanswered' duplicate: With introduciton of React 19, how would you implement a refetch on some value change

Ok I am still not sure what the warning means thou in this instance, was use not meant to take on a promise, surely we do not need a framework to use Suspense right?. Also I did fix this by using a key on JokeItem but was interested on this approach with use only

was use not meant to take on a promise It can take a promise, but you need to make sure its the exact same promise each time the component renders. Creating a new promise on every render causes the warning i linked. So in order to load data via use, you must implement or import a solution for caching promises.

@NicholasTower I see, they are working on the promise caching, I think this would be a great use case for use imo

const userPromise = fetchData();

const JokeItem = () => {
    const joke = use(userPromise);
    return <h2>{joke.value}</h2>;
};

It’s important to note that use in React 19 doesn’t support promises created during the render phase, so they must be created outside of this phase, as was done with userPromise.
